# Laravel 5 query second page append query string issue

Tags: laravel

In Lravel4 I can append the query string to the second page by using following code

```
 <?php echo $customers->appends(Input::all())->render(); ?>
```

But, the same code is not working in Laravel5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some changes in newer version of laravel so try replacing Input with Request.

`<?php echo $customers->appends(Input::all())->render(); ?>`

Change the above code to the following:

`<?php echo $customers->appends(Request::all())->render(); ?>`